# Funcion logaritmo en python

Tags: python, tkinter

No soy capaz de que me de el valor del logaritmo. Utilizo la librería Tcl/Tk.
Debería devolver el resultado.

```
def logaritmo():
    try:  
        _valor1 = int(entrada_texto.get())
        resultado1 = int(str(math.log(_valor1)))  
        
        etiqueta3.config(compound = "top", bitmap ="",text=resultado1,bg="gray13",foreground="white")
    except ValueError:
        etiqueta3.config(compound = "left", bitmap ="error",text="ERROR Introduce un numero",bg="red")
```

Comment: *No soy capaz de que me de el valor del logaritmo* -> Esto no nos dice absolutamente nada de lo que está pasando. Por un momento imagínate que no tienes ni idea de qué sucede cuando ejecutas ese código, y alguien te dice eso... entenderías algo??? Pues eso está pasando aquí! Está genial poner el código en cuestión, pero si no nos dices también cual es el error ***exacto*** que tienes, cómo vamos a saber solucionarlo? Por favor, además del código añade tanto el error concreto que te da, como el resultado que esperas obtener ***siempre que preguntes***

Comment: Se trata de que devuelva el resultado del logaritmo en la etiqueta nada más.

Comment: Hablo en general, en todas las preguntas, se debe añadir siempre: 1) El código fuente, 2) El ***ERROR*** explicado (PERO EL ERROR CONCRETO, "no funciona" no es un error), 3) Un ejemplo de una salida correcta. Aquí cumples dos requisitos, pero no veo en ningún lado ***QUÉ ERROR TIENES***.

Comment: Qué logaritmo esperas obtener (**¿en que base?**) la función math.log() con sólo un parámetro devuelve **logaritmo natural**, *logaritmo con base **e*** que es diferente de logaritmo con base 10 (que es el que llamamos logaritmo a secas en lenguaje cotidiano). Explica mejor lo que quieres obtener... y, por favor acostúmbrate a leer la documentación [Math module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/math.html)

Comment: Fijate de hacer caso a los consejos que te dan para que la pregunta sea utilizada por alguien que puede tener el mismo problema y encontrar una respuesta acorde.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

La base por defecto de `math.log` es el número e. Si quieres calcularlo en base 10, tienes que especificarlo así: `math.log(_valor1,10)`.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor haz el [tour] y consulta [answer]. Como puedes notar, estás jugando a adivinar cual es el problema del OP. Pues el no fue capaz de presentarlo con claridad. Y, en esas circunstancias **no es correcto ofrecer respuestas, que presuponen una pregunta que eventualmente no corresponde a lo respondido.**

Comment: Pues yo le he entendido perfectamente.

Comment: Gracias!! Quedó perfecto!! ;) @JonathanPréstamoRodríguez